# apropos / find context related information

Tags: python, find

On unix-like systems we have **apropos** to search the manual page names and descriptions so we can find context related information.

For example *apropos delete* would give me a list of all kinds of software related to "deleting" stuff. Does anybody know if that already exist for Python or do I have to code it?

What I basically want is the same semantics seen with the Unix apropos in Python ... find context related modules/functions/etc. I am not talking about doing a search on PyPi but rather find stuff when I am offline for example.

Cheers,
Markus

Answer (score 1):

> > I am not talking about doing a search on PyPI!

why not ? that should be the first thing you do if you want to look for Python modules. Otherwise simple search on google/yahoo may yield some results, such as [this](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~nati/Python/apropos.py)

Comment: sure but then I'd like to be able to search through things locally installed in cases I am offline e.g. sitting on some plane etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ apt-cache search <keyword> | grep python
```